# How to implement Fog Of War with an shader?

Tags: unity, shaders, hlsl, fog-of-war

Okay, I'm creating a RTS game and want to implement an AgeOfEmpires-like Fog Of War(FOW).
That means a tile(or pixel) can be:

- 0% transparent (unexplored)
- 50% transparent black (explored but not in viewrange)
- 100% transparent(explored and in viewrange)

RTS means I'll have many **explorers** (NPCs, buildings, ...). Okay, so I have an 2d array of bytes `byte[,] explored`. The byte value correlates the transparency.

The question is, how do I pass this array to my shader? Well I think it is not possible to pass an entire array. So: **what technique shall I use to let my shader know if a pixel/tile is visible or not?**

Comment: Note that fair fog of war shows what player last saw in explored area. If player explored a forest and went away, he should still see a forest even if it is chopped long ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. And it is called texture. 

Textures [are not just pictures](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Texturing/Tutorial%2014.html) - it can be any kind of data*. 
Another option would per-vertex data - if you dont mind smooth border between (un)explored. Or just as other post suggested - pass it as per-tile uniform.  
 
 * *Ofcourse, you need to stay in reasonable array size, defined by maximum texture size. Also note that editing such texture would mean sending it all over again, which could be slow.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess 256^2 (or more) tiles are a bit too much for a texture based solution :) Hmm.. Reading through the [Unity Shader Documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ShadersOverview.html) I'm not sure if I can pass a uniform per-tile. Well, seems like I would have to get deeper into this topic.

Comment: You don't necessarily have smooth borders between explored and unexplored. It depends on the way your vertices are laid out. And you don't even have to re-send the texture. You could simply update it with another shader by rendering to it.

Comment: For example GTX 760 supports textures up to 16384pix big in any dimension (16k*16k). At least 512 should be ok on any device(at least my phone managed it), if the texture would not suffice, you would have to use more of them. As for per-tile, just render tiles one by one, setting uniform(s) before each individual call. The cleanest solution would probably be per-vertex though as you can render it in one call and you are not limited by the texture size.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to draw-calls in unity.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know much about unity - I can only help you with theory. Well... you dont need draw calls for the 2nd solution, do you? Per-vertex data could be allowed, since how you you supply coords, normals, etc.. Note that even for texture solution you need to pass/calculate UV somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I'd simply provide a uniform per tile. For example a simple float that indicates the transparency.
Before you render the tile, you simply set the uniform.
If that's not possible, try using vertex attributes (also using a simple float).

Comment: **When I get it right** this would be kinda awful since I would have to declare `(map.width/tilesize) * (map.height/tilesize)` uniforms in my shader? Also this would make it annoying to have custom map sizes. Well I'm a shader nobbie and most likely I've get it wrong :/

Comment: No, that's not correct. You have a single uniform in your shader. For example "uniform float transparency;". I suggest you to learn how to work with shaders, before trying to implement this. Once you learned how they work, you'll answer your question easily by yourself. :D